# Draw route on google maps with animation objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, routes

How can I draw route on google map with an animation effect, 
How can I upload proper Latitude and Longitude to local server after some time interval, This data must be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Below answers for drawing route between two latitude and longitude with animation.

```
NSInteger animatePathIndex;
NSTimer *animationTimer;

GMSPath *path;
GMSMutablePath *animatePath;
GMSPolyline *animatePolyline;

- (void)fetchPolylineWithOrigin:(CLLocation *)origin destination:(CLLocation *)destination {
    NSString *originString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", origin.coordinate.latitude, origin.coordinate.longitude];
    NSString *destinationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", destination.coordinate.latitude, destination.coordinate.longitude];
    NSString *directionsAPI = @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?";
    NSString *directionsUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&origin=%@&destination=%@&mode=driving", directionsAPI, originString, destinationString];
    NSURL *directionsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:directionsUrlString];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *fetchDirectionsTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:directionsUrl completionHandler:
     ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
         NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
         if(error) {
             //Error in fetching poline
             return;
         }

         NSArray *routesArray = [json objectForKey:@"routes"];

         if ([routesArray count] > 0) {
             NSDictionary *routeDict = [routesArray objectAtIndex:0];
             NSDictionary *routeOverviewPolyline = [routeDict objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"];
             NSString *points = [routeOverviewPolyline objectForKey:@"points"];
             GMSPath *path = [GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:points];
             [self drawPathWithOutAnimation:path];
         }
     }];
    [fetchDirectionsTask resume];
}

-(void)drawPathWithAnimation:(GMSPath *)newPath {
    path = newPath;
    animatePolyline = [[GMSPolyline alloc] init];
    animatePath = [[GMSMutablePath alloc] init];
    animatePathIndex = 0;

    [animationTimer invalidate];
    animationTimer = nil;

    //Whenever timer is triggered it will draw path
    animationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.003  target:self selector:@selector(animatePolylinePath) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)animatePolylinePath {

    //After animaiton completed it will go to else case
    if (animatePathIndex < path.count) {
        [animatePath addCoordinate:[path coordinateAtIndex:animatePathIndex]];
        animatePolyline.path = animatePath;
        animatePolyline.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
        animatePolyline.strokeWidth = 2.5;

        animatePolyline.geodesic = YES;
        NSArray *styles = @[[GMSStrokeStyle solidColor:PathColor],
                        [GMSStrokeStyle solidColor:PathColor]];
        NSArray *lengths = @[@100000, @50000];
        animatePolyline.spans = GMSStyleSpans(animatePolyline.path, styles, lengths, kGMSLengthRhumb);
        animatePolyline.map = self.mapView;
        animatePathIndex += 1;
    }
    else {
        animatePathIndex = 0;
        [animationTimer invalidate];
        animationTimer = nil;
    }
}
```

For your another question, call local server api at which time you want to send location.

Comment: hello what is DropMaker over here?

Comment: ignore DropMaker, Actually i was using that in my project. Now i updated the code